# How do I reference an image path to my PHP File?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am a student and I have been given a project to do, we made a database in MySql called Video_Game_Shop. Then we had to connect it to a website using PHP and HTML. And we have to show on one page all the games in our database listed. So we did that by calling a procedure which ordered the games by price. This is where I have the problem. We now need to show images for every one of these games on the page. What I have done so far I have downloaded the pictures, for every game we have listed, and I have no idea on how to do that task. I heard of some ways of inputting the path for the images or to use BLOB file type, but I don't know how to do any of that. I will add the PHP file so you can more easily understand my situation.   I would be very grateful if you could help me. :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet"                   href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<style>
    h1 {font-family:Serif; font-size:22px; text-align:center}
    p {font-family:Serif; font-size:16px}
    .container {
        width: 100%;
        clear: both;
        opacity: 1
    }
    input[type=number] {
        border:2px #ffo; 
        opacity:0.2}
    input[type=text] {
        border:2px #ff0; 
        opacity:0.2}
    input[type=date] {
        border:2px #ff0; 
        opacity:0.2}

</style>
<h1>videogames</h1>

    <head>
        <title>videogames</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/table.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body background="http://i.imgur.com/yGkEuwZ.jpg">
        <?php
        require_once 'user.php';
        try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",
                            $username, $password);
            // execute the stored procedure
            $sql = 'CALL List_game_by_price()';
            $q = $conn->query($sql);
            $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } catch (PDOException $pe) {
            die("Error occurred:" . $pe->getMessage());
        }
        ?>
        <div class="container">
        <table border="1" align="center" width="90%">
            <tr>
                <th>GameID</th>
                <th>Name/th>
                <th>Developer</th>
                <th>Publisher</th>
                <th>ESRB</th>
                <th>Relase Date</th>
                <th>Platform</th>
                <th>Genre</th>
                <th>Language</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
        <?php while ($r = $q->fetch()): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $r['GameID'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $r['Name'] ?> </td>
                    <td><?php echo $r['Developer'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $r['Publisher']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $r['ESRB'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo date_format ($r['Relase Date']) ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $r['Platform'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $r['Genre'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $r ['Language'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $r['Price'] ?></td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Upload the images to an ftp, input your image names in a column and then call that in your query. Might be a bit of a workaround but it works well!

Comment: could you be more specific with you method, i added the column and uploaded the pictures, i put in the names as well. then i made a new procedure and called it in the code above. I added this line  " <td><?php echo '<img src="path/to/'.$r['GameID'].'.jpg" />' ?></td>"   and it showed me like instead of the pictures i uploaded, the standard icon for pictures, could you help me

Comment: <td><img src="path/to/<?= $r['GameID'] ?>.jpg" /></td>

Comment: do i change the path/to part with the path to my images on the FTP

Comment: Yeah. But keep in mind where your folder is and where your file is located :). I made an answer so you can comment there if you want :)

Comment: I don't think you need the /var/www/html in there. Just go from your root, which I think is <img src="grp03/videoGamePictures/w?= $r['GameID'] ?>.jpg" />

Comment: it still only shows the icon for images yet not the real images

Comment: Is it possible to see the page? Also, if you see the icon, it means that the path is off. Try to fix that :)

Comment: <td><img src="grp03/videoGamePictures/w?= $r['Pic'] ?>.jpg"/></td> That is what I see when looking at your page source. I think you missed the < when starting the php tag. <?=

Comment: which php tag do you mean

Comment: Change <td><img src="grp03/videoGamePictures/w?= $r['Pic'] ?>.jpg"/></td> to <td><img src="grp03/videoGamePictures/<?= $r['Pic'] ?>.jpg"/></td>

Comment: Looks like you don't have shorttags enabled. Change to <td><img src="grp03/videoGamePictures/<?php echo $r['Pic']; ?>.jpg"/></td>

Comment: Also, Name/th>  should be Name</th>

Comment: still the same   result

Comment: Did you use <td><img src="grp03/videoGamePictures/<?php echo $r['Pic']; ?>.jpg"/></td>?? That should work

Comment: You're very close with the fix for your problem. I know what you need to do. Don't give up now!

Answer (score 3):

A quick solution without changing your database at all would be to upload images to the FTP and rename them for their name to match the GameID.

Example: Change your Mass-Effect2_600x400.jpg into 1.jpg.

In your fetch (where you show the data from the base) just add another something like this

```
<td><?php echo '<img src="path/to/'.$r['GameID'].'.jpg" />' ?></td>
```

Comment: in which part of the code would I add this line and do i have to write it multiple times for every game or will it automatically show all images

Answer (score 0):

You could create an assets table with cols [ID Primary Key], [Url]. Create a foreign key on your products table AssetID. This way you only have one record per image URL, and multiple products can use that image.

Upload the files to FTP and insert records into the assets table.

If you really wanted to go above and beyond your task, you could create an image upload for the products from an Admin panel. Which when uploaded inserts the path into the assets table and assigns the AssetID to the product.

Answer (score 0):

Upload the images to an ftp, input your image names in a column and then call that in your query. Might be a bit of a workaround but it works well!

```
<td><img src="path/to/<?= $r['GameID'] ?>.jpg" /></td>
```